# Doing "Your Second iOS App" tutorial. Can't get rid of this warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, viewcontroller

I'm doing the "Your Second iOS App" tutorial on the Apple iOS developer site: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CreatingAddView/CreatingAddView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH6-SW4

It has a MasterViewController with a Table, connected to an AddSightingViewController that allows the user to add a new object to the table. In the MasterViewController I had to implement the following method that gets called when the user is done creating an object in the AddSightingViewController.

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReturnInput"]) {
        AddSightingViewController *addController = [segue sourceViewController];
        if (addController.birdSighting) {
            [self.dataController addBirdSightingWithSighting:addController.birdSighting];
            [[self tableView] reloadData];
        }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

But when this piece of code gets called I get this warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UINavigationController: 0x8961f10> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

I'm not sure I understand what dismissViewControllerAnimated does exactly. I'm guessing it dismisses the AddSightViewController because the user is done adding a new object, but shouldn't it be [addController dissmissViewController.....] or something?

Comment: That's an unwind segue method right so the dismissal should be happening anyway so no need to manually call any dismiss method I'd have thought...

Comment: You're right, if I remove the dismiss line it gets rid of the warning and doesn't break any of the functionality. I guess it's just a mistake in the Apple tutorial. Thanks. Could still explain the rational behind calling [self dismissViewController] when we want to get rid of the modalViewController. I would expect [self dismissViewController] to apply to the MasterViewController, which is currently open and shouldn't be removed.

Comment: The docs say "The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller."